# Is there any possibility of storing any page outside of web space in php?

Tags: php, security

I want to store secure hash programming outside OF the web space and wanted this algorithm to perform actions in the background that can happen if and only if there is possibility of storing this page outside the web space.

How to store outside the web space?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform a task in the background, you could call a PHP script from Cron - and so you could store the file anywhere on the system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to restrict access from web-browser?

Make new directory Secret and put files restricted for web-browser-users and add .htaccess file and put there

```
Deny From all
```

that's it

Comment: Would that still allow access to scripts running on the server? I'm incredibly unfamiliar with web/server admin/set-up...

Comment: @DavidThomas: sure it would. He would like to run BG proccess

Comment: Thanks; although I was asking for purely personal reasons, rather than anything related to the OP's question. =)